# Unable to add row dynamically in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am beginner to salesforce. I want to add row dynamically to VF page when i clicked add row button.

this is my script

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c"  extensions="Cutomextension">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Employee__c}" var="emp">
            <apex:column headerValue=" Employee Name">
               <apex:inputField value="{!emp.name}"/>
            </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Add Row"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class Cutomextension {

    public Employee__c emp {get; set;}
    public List<Employee__c> empList {get; set;}
    public static Integer addCount {get; set;}

    public Cutomextension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.emp = (Employee__c)Controller.getRecord();
        empList = new List<employee__c>();
    }

    public void add() {
        empList.add(new employee__c());
    }
}
```

When i clicked add row button, new row doesn't get added. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to show a list of records in your page. Please read the following articles about showing a set of records in a pages and try to code it for your case.

- [Custom List Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_custom_list_controller.htm)
- [Standard List Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_controller_sosc_about.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_controller_sosc_about.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)
- [dynamically add rows in visualforce page 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000963NIAQ)
- [dynamically add rows in visualforce page 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000097CwIAI)

  If you have any further question after reading the articles above please add an update to this question.

Comment: I checkd with all the functionality but its not working.Is I need to use wrapper class here???